# Silverstripe 2.4 default value textareafield CustomSiteConfig

Tags: silverstripe

How can default value be set for textareafield in CustomSiteConfig?
This doesnt work:

```
class CustomSiteConfig extends DataObjectDecorator {

    function extraStatics() {
        return array(
            'db' => array(
                'MyText' => 'Text'),
            'defaults' => array( 
                'MyText' => 'Bla Bla'),
            'has_one' => array(
                'Logo' => 'Image')
        );

    }

public function updateCMSFields(FieldSet $fields) {

        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextareaField("MyText", "My Text"));
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new ImageField('Logo', 'Logo'));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the statics do not work, probable this untested (since 2.4 is so far away) snippet could help:

```
public function populateDefaults() {
    parent::populateDefaults();
    $this->owner->MyText = 'Bla Bla';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works, but maybe not how you expect.

The `defaults` array allows you to specify simple static values to be the default value for when a record is created. If a record is already created then the values from the defaults array will not be used, even when adding a new variable to that database table.

If you were adding a database variable to a `Page`, rather than the `SiteConfig`, and specified it's default value in the `defaults` array, all existing pages would not get that default value but any new page created after that point would.

Because the `SiteConfig` record has already been created `MyText` does not get the default value.

If you create a new site with your code and run `dev/build` you would find your `SiteConfig` `MyText` variable **will** have the default value of `"bla bla"`.